# Creating R package, what is .Rcheck folder? and how to create .tar.gz file?

Tags: r

I am trying to create an R package by using "Rstudio" for the first time ^_*. Actually, I wrote all the functions in several "R scripts" and the documentation by using roxygen2.

I loaded and built (Ctrl+Shift+B) and it works "DONE(packageName)", I used roxgen2::roxgenise() for documentation and all ".Rd files" have been created in "man" folder. Also, I checked the package (Ctrl+Shift+E) and I got "status: OK" and "R CMD check succeeded".

I mean everything is working well. My questions are - there is a folder "packageName.Rcheck" has been created, what is this folder? And is it important for creating the ".tar.gz" file?

Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel, isn`t fair for what?!! How did I write most of the package? sure after reading the entire manual. I did understand most of it but the last part, honestly I did not understand it that is why I asked.. Please, if you do not like any question, simply just ignore it but claiming that people do not want to read or  they ask you to read instead of them, in my opinion is not a good way!.